# Multiple definitions of `GamepadControll::GamepadControll()'

Tags: c++, linker, definition

I got this error message:

> multiple definition of `GamepadControll::GamepadControll()'

After being frustrated for hours I reduced the code to:

GamepadControll.h:

```
#ifndef GAMEPADCONTROLL_H_
#define GAMEPADCONTROLL_H_

#include <iostream>

class GamepadControll {
public:
    GamepadControll();
    virtual ~GamepadControll();
};

#endif /* GAMEPADCONTROLL_H_ */
```

GamepadControl.cpp:

```
#include "GamepadControll.h"

GamepadControll::GamepadControll() {
    std::cout << "Hello, I work!" << std::endl;
}

GamepadControll::~GamepadControll() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}
```

But I just get this error message!

//Edit:
Main isn't defined.. Can't I run only a class without mainfiles like in java? Here is the whole eclipse Project: [http:/ul.to/m37d2z](http://http:/ul.to/m37d2z)

Comment: You'll have to give more info about where you are compiling this code. Compiler/IDE? Where is main() defined?

Comment: Main isn't defined.. Can't I run only a class without mainfiles like in java?

Here is the whole eclipse Project:
http://ul.to/m37d2z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most mulitply-defined-symbol error situations tend to be caused by including code into two different compilation units.

Are you sure that you're not including `GamepadControl.cpp` into one of your other source files?

For example, with both your files and a `main.cpp` holding:

```
#include "GamepadControll.h"
int main (void) { return 0; }
```

I get no errors with `g++ main.cpp GamepadControll.cpp`. If I change that first line to:

```
#include "GamepadControll.cpp"
```

and compile with the same command, I get:

```
/tmp/ccbu52oq.o: In function `GamepadControll::GamepadControll()':
GamepadControll.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of
    `GamepadControll::GamepadControll()'
```

The only other possibility I can think of is if you're explicitly including the code file twice. Using the error-free version of `main.cpp` above, I *still* get the error when I use:

```
g++ main.cpp GamepadControll.cpp GamepadControll.cpp
```

If it's neither of those two cases, your best bet is to provide the *full* details of your situation. That means every source file (including the main one), the compile and link commands you're using, and the environment (e.g., gcc3 under Linux, Code::Blocks on Windows).

Comment: thx
I just thought I needn't something like a main file, where the class is included. Ohhh.. these JAVA influence ^^

Answer (score 0):

From this sample code, there seems to be no error. The error could be multiple defined constructor `GamepadControll`.

Please search the constructor in code base and find any multiple instances defined

```
GamepadControll::GamepadControll()
```

Other possibility: check if you have defined constructor in header file ( which does not look to be the case from the sample code though)